# PHP all GET parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am designing my application. And I should make the next things. All GET parameters (?var=value) with help of mod_rewrite should be transform to the /var/value. How can I do this? I have only 1 .php file (index.php), because I am usign the FrontController pattern. Can you help me with this mod_rewrite rules?
Sorry for my english. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That sounds horrifying for both you and your users.  Generally, it is a good idea to make your path look like what specifies content, but leave other parameters alone.  For example, instead of /content.php?id=5, you might have /content/5.  If you have a handful of options for something though, you may want to do something like /content/5?opt1=something&opt2=something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do something like this on sites that use 'seo-friendly' URLs.

In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Then on index.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/home") {
    include ("home.php");
}
```

The .htaccess rule tells it to load index.php if the file or directory asked for was not found.  Then you just parse the request URI to decide what index.php should do.

Answer (score 6):

The following code in your .htaccess will rewrite your URL from eg. `/api?other=parameters&added=true` to `/?api=true&other=parameters&added=true`

```
RewriteRule ^api/           /index.php?api=true&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# generic: ?var=value
# you can retrieve /something by looking at $_GET['something']
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?var=$1

# but depending on your current links, you might
# need to map everything out. Examples:

# /users/1
# to: ?p=users&userId=1
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$ /?p=users&userId=$1

# /articles/123/asc
# to: ?p=articles&show=123&sort=asc
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/(asc|desc)$ /?p=articles&show=$1&sort=$2

# you can add /? at the end to make a trailing slash work as well:
# /something or /something/
# to: ?var=something
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?var=$1
```

The first part is the URL that is received. The second part the rewritten URL which you can read out using `$_GET`. Everything between `(` and `)` is seen as a variable. The first will be `$1`, the second `$2`. That way you can determine exactly where the variables should go in the rewritten URL, and thereby know how to retrieve them.

You can keep it very general and allow "everything" by using `(.+)`. This simply means: one or more (the `+`) of any character (the `.`). Or be more specific and e.g. only allow digits: `[0-9]+` (one or more characters in the range 0 through 9). You can find a lot more information on regular expressions on http://www.regular-expressions.info/. And this is a good site to test them: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK mod_rewrite doesn't deal with parameters after the question mark — regexp end-of-line for rewrite rules matches the end of path before the '?'. So, you're pretty much limited to passing the parameters through, or dropping them altogether upon rewriting.