# Simple search that redirects to /user/"searchterm"/

Tags: html, forms

Currently I'm working with:

```
<form action="/user/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="" id="" size="20" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

But, this redirects to `/user/?=searchterm`

I would like it to redirect to `/user/searchterm`

I know this is easy I just cannot figure it out.

EDIT: If I was unclear. I would like the form to use the parameter typed in and redirect the browser to /user/(parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have two options to do this.

1. Redirect the user after for submit to the correct page (example using PHP):

   #### HTML

   ```
   <form action="/usersearch/" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="user" id="" size="20" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </form>
   ```

   #### PHP

   ```
   if (!isset($_REQUEST['user'])) {
       header('Location: http://example.com/search'); //redirect back to search page
       exit();
   }

   header('Location: http://example.com/user/' . $_REQUEST['user']);
   exit();
   ```
2. Use javascript to capture the submit and redirect (I'm using jQuery because I'm lazy ATM but it's alo possible with vanilla JS):

   ```
   ​(function($) {
       $('form').submit(function() {
           window.location = "http://example.com/user/" + $('input[name="user"]', this).val();

           return false;
       });
   })(jQuery)​
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It can't (and shouldn't!) be done in regular HTML. You'll need to use **JavaScript** to **fake** the form submission (by redirecting to the link according to the search term, and using **URL rewriting** to point to the correct `$_GET` variable'ed address).

Comment: What if JavaScript is turned off? Might as well send them to a search page where they are given a list of possible pages that they were searching for.

Comment: It's not possible with JavaScript turned off. Period. And that's a good thing.

Comment: O its possible. Its even possible to mess with JavaScript, because its a Client Side code. http://www.google.com/search?q=Turn+off+Javascript+in&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @Chillie: What he's looking for, changing the address looks after form submission, is impossible without JavaScript. It's hard to do even **with** JavaScript. You need to either fake the button, or mess with the form submission, which both suck. So don't.

Comment: Even if js is turned off you can make this work it would just fall back on something like `/user/?q=something`

Comment: @Chillie javascript is turned on by default.

Comment: @webarto JavaScript isn't in all browsers

Comment: @Chillie for [1% of the users](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/) I wouldn't care. And as said this will gracefully fall back

Comment: @sg3s 1% is still millions of users, for a fall back, then you need more than just JavaScript. you'd need to have your site able able to accept `/user/?q=something` without using JavaScript, so like Truth said to begin with don't do it.

Comment: @Chillie: You should be having your site support that in the first place! Heard of [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)? Please, when 3 people tell you you are wrong, and there's a better way to do it, please, admit you may be wrong and let's move on.

Comment: @Truth I don't believe I'm having three people telling me I'm wrong, I believe I'm having three people telling my there opinions. Doesn't matter though, We all have them, and they are all worth something. Any you are are right, you should admit your wrong when you didn't even know that JavaScript can be turned off and that's the Truth! LOL!

Comment: @Chillie: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

```
<form action="/user/" method="get">
```

To This:

```
<form action="/user/" method="post">
```

By using `get`, the values are added to the URL. By using `post` the values are not added to the URL.

EDIT:
Misread question...

I'm not sure why you want to do that, It will make the link act kinda like a page link, but anyway, I would suggest using a [mod_rewrite](http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/mod_rewrite.php) if you are using Apache. There is another question on here with a good answer that might help. You would just need to have the value

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674388/1076164

Comment: Yeah... I'm looking for the form to pass a parameter (sorry if thats unclear) So if "x" is the parameter, when the form is submitted, the result will redirect to /user/x

Answer (score 0):

Changing '/user/?=searchterm' to '/user/searchterm' is hard to do; changing '/user/q=searchterm' to '/user/searchterm' is easier using either .htaccess file or mod-rewrite.
Querystrings should always be in the format '?q=a'; having it in the format '?=a' doesn't make much sense.